# Removed profile photo still appears on my contacts WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, contact-photo

I am using WhatsApp and have a profile photo set. I updated this picture several times. Now I noticed that on the phone of my first contact there is an old profile photo displayed. On the phone of my second contact there is an even older photo displayed. I removed the picture on my phone successfully though.

Solution attempt:

- I restarted WhatsApp on my phone and the phone of my first contact.
- I cleared the cache of WhatsApp on my phone.

Result: The old picture is still shown.

What am I doing wrong?

Profile picture is set to "My contacts" in

Settings -> Account -> Privacy -> Profile photo -> My contacts.

[image: Privacy]

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62963/whatsapp-friends-profile-image-not-showing) as I want my picture to be removed from my contacts WhatsApp.

Comment: What do you mean by "on the phone of my first contact"? Do you mean that when checking your profile on your fronds phone, they still see your old picture? Does the other phone have a working internet connection?

Comment: Exactly. Of course it has a working internet connection.

Comment: Strange. I find that sometimes only after i press on a friend's profile picture then it changes. If i don't press, it won't change. But it seems like you've tried everything. Did you try setting it that all contacts should see the profile? Maybe that will change it

Comment: I pressed it to maximize it. The old one is displayed in a very poor resolution. I had the settings that no contact shall see the picture (as this is my current intention to remove the picture), did not change anything.

Comment: I want to remove my photo from all my contacts phones, I reformulated the question.

Answer (score 2):

This almost always happens with me. Your contact's WhatsApp hasn't refreshed the changed profile photo from the Server and hence it is displaying the low resolution cache version of the old photo.

There's nothing you need to do on your phone. Try to refresh the contacts list on your friend's phone. That's best you can try as the problem is not on your side.